# yasnippets - finding and modifying some snippets

Tags: yasnippet

I'm struggling a bit with yasnippet. My question must be very basic but I would like to modify some snippets but I can't locate them. 
I have for example a snippet `style` for `html-mode` but it does not appear where it should be that is either under :

```
~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet
```

or

```
~/.emacs.d/snippets
```

My config is the following:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path
         "~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-20160801.1142")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
(add-to-list 'yas-snippet-dirs "~/.emacs.d/snippets")
```

Any would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

Considering your configuration, using *elpa*, they are located in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-20160801.1142/snippets`.

Your custom snippets should be at `~/.emacs.d/snippets` so they don't get overwritten in each update. Also check the value of the variable `yas-snippets-dirs` with `Ctr-h v yas-snippets-dir`.

Answer (score 5):

In your buffer, `M-x yas-visit-snippet-file`, then type the name of the snippet you want to edit, or choose from a prompted list. Then it will open a buffer for you to edit. From the buffer you can `M-: buffer-file-name` to see the path of the file containing the snippet.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to edit a snippet from the mode you are in just press the standard commands :

`C-c & C-v` to view an existing snippet (you should know what name it has)

or

`C-c & C-n` to create a new snippet for the mode you're in.

In this way you don't have to care about where the snippets are located, YASnippet should do that automatically.

You can also open existing/new snippets by clicking on the menu bar YASnippet (if you're using the GUI).

I hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `(setq yas-snippet-dirs '("~/.emacs.d/snippets"))`

When you miss a snippet, that you've already created, use `yas-reload-all`.

And you don't need the first line.